# SQL Add hours for employees

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table for employees signing in and out. They have a date and time field for in and out and an PersonID number that links to the employees name etc.

I need to work out the difference between the 2 dates and times then add them all together for each employee.

```
    select a.*,
           b.timein, 
           b.timeout, 
           datediff(mi,b.timein,b.timeout) as total_mins 
    from tbl_people a 
    left join tbl_register b on a.id=b.personid
```

Output:

```
+----+-----------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------+
| ID | FirstName | LastName |         TimeIn          |         TimeOut         | Total_Mins |
+----+-----------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------+
|  1 | David     | Test     | 2015-05-12 12:11:00.000 | 2015-05-12 12:13:00.000 |          2 |
|  2 | David     | Test     | 2015-05-12 12:15:00.000 | 2015-05-12 12:18:00.000 |          3 |
+----+-----------+----------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------+
```

This is what im currently getting. I would like it to show one record for each person with the total amount of minutes worked.

Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have at least 2 options:

Option 1 - Use [`DISTINCT`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp) and [`SUM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) with [`OVER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*, 
       SUM(DATEDIFF(mi, b.timein, b.timeout)) OVER(PARTITION BY a.id) AS total_mins 
FROM tbl_people a 
LEFT JOIN tbl_register b ON a.id=b.personid
```

Option 2 - Use a [derived table](http://logicalread.solarwinds.com/when-to-apply-sql-server-derived-tables-mc03/#.VVH-7vmeDRY) for the [`GROUP BY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) part:

```
SELECT a.*,
       total_mins            
from tbl_people a 
left join (
    SELECT personid, 
           SUM(DATEDIFF(mi, timein, timeout) AS total_mins 
    FROM tbl_register 
    GROUP BY personid 
 ) b ON a.id=b.personid
```

Comment: So should option 2... Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select
    ppl.FirstName + ' ' + ppl.LastName as 'Person',
    sum( datediff(mi, reg.timein, reg.timeout)) as 'total_mins'
from
    tbl_people ppl
    left join tbl_register reg on ppl.id = reg.personid
group by
    ppl.FirstName + ' ' + ppl.LastName
```